# Is a Sitecore campaign triggered as a 'live event'?

Tags: marketing-automation, campaigncreator

In Sitecore, [campaigns](https://doc.sitecore.com/users/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/campaigns.html) can be created for online and offline tracking. Those campaigns can then be triggered by adding `sc_camp=the-unique-id` to urls in social media or on the site itself.

I want to setup a campaign and as soon as the person clicks the link with sc_camp, I want a **[Marketing Automation](https://doc.sitecore.com/users/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/create-a-marketing-automation-campaign.html)** Campaign to kick in.
Currently with Sitecore 9.1 you can already add a rule in the start condition of the MA: `where the contact has triggered campaign x`

With goals, you have to select 'IsLiveEvent' so that the MA gets triggered during the session and not afterwards.
Can this work for campaigns?

Answer (score 4):

Campaigns are not treated as live events OOTB. Live events are only detected for page events and outcomes by corresponding processors:

- `Sitecore.Xdb.MarketingAutomation.Tracking.Pipelines.RegisterPageEvent.LivePageEventInspector`
- `Sitecore.Xdb.MarketingAutomation.Tracking.Pipelines.RegisterOutcome.LiveOutcomeInspector`

Both of the processors check for `IsLiveEvent` property on the marketing entity definition and kicks off `submitLiveAutomationEvent` pipeline if event/outcome matches that criterion.
You could try to simulate similar functionality for campaigns by creating your own `LiveCampaignInspector` processor and patching `triggerCampaign` pipeline.

```
public class LiveCampaignInspector : TriggerCampaignProcessor
{
    public override void Process(TriggerCampaignArgs args)
    {
        new SubmitLiveAutomationEventPipeline().Run(new SubmitLiveAutomationEventArgs(args.Page.Session.Contact, args.Page.Session.Interaction, args.Definition.Id));
    }
}
```

Please note that I didn't have a chance to test it.

Comment: please note that a live event is not really "live". It means that actions that are triggered by those events can be handled during the same session and that an xConnect update isnt needed. Marketing automation runs async and has a delay (which can be configured). I wanted it to run immediately, but there always seems to be a delay of ~2seconds, when I decreased the automation plan time.